# get form data wordpress in same page

Tags: database, wordpress, forms, request

I am learning word press. I have 2 questions

I have created a page and assigned my template file for it.

### 1. Question

How to get my form input values in same page or in another page template?

```
<form id="formId" action="" method="post">
    <input style="width:88%" type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" name="subs" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In same file I put:

```
<?php
    if( isset($_POST['subs']) ) {
        echo $_POST['name'];
    }
?>
```

I also tried `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` in action but it's not displayed.

How could I store it in my own table?

When click `submit`, it refreshes and displays "No Results Found".

### 2. Question

How to show the submitted values in `wp-admin`?

Here's the [word press code flow](http://codex.wordpress.org/User%3aDavidHouse/Wordpress_Code_Flow) I can't solve.

Answer (score 0):

Change Form action to the same page:

```
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>
```

Comment: I think there is any functions to get From Input  values

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"
```

instead of

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
```

in your form